# Why does df.shift() not work when using modin?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, modin

In the following example code I am trying to use the df.shift() function which pandas normally executes flawlessly. However, when using modin, the .shift() function ceases to work. Is there any way to fix this?

```
import modin.pandas as pd
import ray
ray.init(runtime_env={'env_vars': {'__MODIN_AUTOIMPORT_PANDAS__': '1'}})

df = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')

df['test'] = 1
df['shift'] = df['test'].shift()
```

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 604402 elements

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/5373) in Modin. To work around the bug, you can use modin's [_to_pandas](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/896#issuecomment-564445814) method, apply the method on the pandas dataframe, then convert the result back to Modin, e.g.:

```py
import modin.pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(-1,4), columns=list(range(4)), index=[0,1,2,0])
pandas_df = df._to_pandas()
pandas_result = pandas_df[0].shift(1)
modin_result = pd.Series(pandas_result)
print(modin_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Mahesh's comment (since I don't have enough reputation to add a comment), a fix has now been merged into main: https://github.com/modin-project/modin/pull/5823